# Respiration of an animal cell media

Tags: lab-techniques, cell-culture, cellular-respiration

I want to do respiration process of an animal cell media in laboratory environment.

I don't entirely sure how to supply it with Oxygen to the process because it is a gas, but not a liquid.

Comment: You want to grow animal cells in cell culture flasks?

Comment: @Chris I wanted to grow them in petri dishes, but I'll check it out!

Comment: That's basically the same.

Comment: @Chris so yes, I consider it as laboratory environment. I just look for a technique of supply.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Chris So are you basically saying I can just put Oxygen into container with a cell and it will absorb it by diffusion? I ask just to clarify.

Comment: @CubaQ it sounds as if you have little or no experience with growing animal cells in culture.  Be aware that there is a lot to know, and if you do things wrong (even slightly wrong) the cells will die very rapidly.  This isn't something you can improvise off the top of your head.

Comment: @CubaQ Yes, that's how it is done in the lab. If you have special requirements (higher or lower oxygen content) you will have to adapt this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supply of cells growing in adherent culture is unproblematic, as long as you don't fill too much media in the petri dish/cell culture flask.

Oxygen supply here work by diffusion which is getting more problematic if the layer of media covering the cells gets to thick. I usually follow the recommendations of Corning for the amount of media to be used in the flasks/dishes:

[image]

The complete information can be found [here](http://csmedia2.corning.com/LifeSciences/Media/pdf/cc_surface_areas.pdf), other companies have similar data sheets available. With these amounts I do a lot of cell culture work and I have no growth problems.

Comment: I used to put 4ml of media in t-25 and 9ml in t-75, and change it in ~2 days. I mostly handled HeLa, HEK, Neuro2a and U87 cells. Worked fine for me.